# Converting Row into Column in mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a table "tbl_option"

The table structure and data are like this:

[image: Table structure]

I want the table structure like:

```
Ques_id   Opt_1    Opt_2    Opt_3    Opt_4
4         abc      def      ijk      lmn
```

can anybody help

Comment: From where the values `abc      def      ijk      lmn` come??

Comment: You should be more specific, we're missing a lot of informations...

Comment: abc def are just example i want data which is in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your source table need a primary key, then it should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `q_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `text` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`, `q_id`, `text`)
VALUES
    (1,1,'test'),
    (2,1,'bbb'),
    (3,1,'aaa'),
    (4,1,'ccc'),
    (5,2,'zzz'),
    (6,2,'yyy'),
    (7,2,'xxx'),
    (8,2,'www');
```

Then maybe this query helps:

```
SELECT a.q_id, a.text t_1, b.text t_2, c.text t_3, d.text t_4
from test_table a
inner join test_table b on a.q_id = b.q_id 
inner join test_table c on b.q_id = c.q_id
inner join test_table d on c.q_id = d.q_id
where
a.id != b.id and
a.id != c.id and
a.id != d.id and
b.id != c.id and
b.id != d.id and
c.id != d.id
group by a.q_id
```

The result is like this:

```
q_id    t_1 t_2 t_3 t_4
1       ccc aaa bbb test
2       www xxx yyy zzz
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the current primary key of each record is. If the primary key is just an arbitrary auto-incremented integer, then your best bet is to write a script in the language of your choice to convert the records into the format that you desire. In PHP, using PDO, I would do something like this:

```
$db = //Your connection string here
$question_ids = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT int_question_id FROM tbl_option");
foreach ($question_ids as $value) {
    $get_questions = $db->prepare("SELECT txt_option FROM tbl_option WHERE int_question_id = :question_id")
    $get_questions->execute(array(":question_id" => $value))
    $questions = $get_questions->fetchAll();      
    $insert_questions = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_new_option (Ques_id,Opt_1,Opt_2,Opt_3,Opt_4) VALUES (:question_id,:option1,:option2,:option3,:option4)");
    $insert_questions->execute(array(":question_id" => $value,":option1" => $questions[0], ":option2" => $questions[1], ":option3" => $questions[2], ":option4" => $questions[3]));
}
```

Of course you would have to set up your new table called tbl_new_option or whatever you wanted beforehand.

Comment: That i already did but it is taking lots of time because the data is more than 1000 row

Comment: @Kuldeep Singh It isn't a fast process refactoring a lot of data. This uses prepared statements which should make it take less time, but otherwise I think you're going to have to let it take its time.